# IntlDateFormatter returning the wrong year

Tags: php, date, intldateformatter

If you run the following code

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2019-12-30 19:45:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_GB',
    null,
    null,
    'Europe/London',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'MMMM YYYY'
);

echo $formatter->format($date);
```

it'll echo `December 2020`. Is this a bug with the class, or have I got something wrong, as I'd expect it to return `December 2019`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to:
https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/

Y stand for year of "Week of Year"(whatever it means) and y is regular year reference we got used to. So to get current year replace `YYYY` with `yyyy` and it should do the job

Answer (score 1):

You are using this function in a bad way. I understand that the ideea is to format the Date and Time in a local specific way.

To write the date and time like a Englishman would do :

> Monday, 30 December 2019 at 19:45:00 Greenwich Mean Time

in the USA Mister Trump would say :

> Monday, December 30, 2019 at 7:45:00 PM Greenwich Mean Time

and for Germany I would say something like :

> Montag, 30. Dezember 2019 um 19:45:00 Mittlere Greenwich-Zeit

Torwald Linus prolly would say in Finland :

> måndag 30 december 2019 kl. 19:45:00 Greenwichtid

and finally in Honduras Pedro de Alvarado would say:

> lunes 30 de diciembre de 2019, 19:45:00 hora del meridiano de Greenwich

(I love this function :) )

because if you desire a result like *2019-12-30* you probably would use format

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-12-30 19:45:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: The code is actually a simplified version of how it's actually used in production, the format `'MMMM YYYY'` is actually passed into a function, so it could be used for changing to a local specific way.